# Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source

Tags: hls.js

i'm trying to play movie by convert to hls stream. 
I convert movie to hls by ffmpeg using this command:

```
nice -n 19 /usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i 9e36f618-5775-40ba-b045-66fd16badc3e.mkv -vf 'movie=/home/thanhtv/data/bitbucket/php/ps/public/img/default/phimsobiz.png [logo]; [in][logo] overlay=5:10' -flags -global_header -f segment -segment_format mpeg_ts -segment_list ./9e36f618-5775-40ba-b045-66fd16badc3e.m3u8 -r 22 -maxrate 2M -bufsize 1M -segment_time 20 -threads 12 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -refs 6 -coder 1 -sc_threshold 40 -flags +loop -me_range 16 -subq 7 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qcomp 0.6 -qdiff 4 -trellis 1 ./9e36f618-5775-40ba-b045-66fd16badc3e%09d.ts
```

but when i play it using hls js ([this one](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/)) i get an error:

```
hls.js:5051 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
    at r.onSBUpdateEnd (https://phimso.biz/assets/js/hls.js:5051:50)
```

with similar command i got another video play, but this one doesn't. I don't know why. Can any one help me please.
[here is the movie](https://phimso.biz/assets/9e36f618-5775-40ba-b045-66fd16badc3e/76f99fe2-0140-40c6-a8e7-9ddc824f9cfd.mkv)

and here is the page i'm trying to play that movie (in hls of course)
https://phimso.biz/admin/test

(my english quite bad, so please forgive me if i made some grammar error)